# bash for loop multiple number ranges

Tags: bash, for, brace-expansion

I want to run a bash numeric 'for' loop but I want to skip some numbers in between.

Example:

```
for num in {1..4, 7..11, 23..34}; do (echo num $num); done
```

or

```
for num in {17..24, 41..48}; do (echo num $num); done
```

1. Is this possible?
2. How?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94445/discussion-on-question-by-skeetastax-bash-for-loop-multiple-number-ranges).

Answer (score 4):

```
for num in {17..24} {41..48}; do (echo num $num); done
```

, and see the documentation for [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) in bash.

Comment: Aha! Syntax! makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone looking for the same answer, I found that:

    for num in {17..24}{41..48}; do (echo num $num); done

is treated as a two-dimensional array, whereas:

    for num in {17..24} {41..48}; do (echo num $num); done

is treated as two 'slices' from a one dimensional array.

Comment: @skeetastax Removing the space between the brace expansions would not involve a two-dimensional array in any way, but it would produce a list of numbers that are the combinations (concatenation) of each number in the first expansion with every number in the second expansion. This is how brace expansions work.

Comment: You are right - I used the wrong term. It is a nested loop concatenating each iterative value.

Comment: For the sake of any other visitors (and my future self), it is a nested loop concatenating each iterative value:
`for num in {17..24}{41..48}; do (echo num $num); done` will concatenate each value from 17 to 24 with each value of 41 to 48 -  e.g. 1741, 1742...1748, 1841, 1842...2448.
`for num in {17..24} {41..48}; do (echo num $num); done` (with the space between "}" and "{") will simply list 17 to 24 followed by 24 to 48.

Comment: @skeetastax: It's not a "nested loop" because it's actually not a loop at all. Try `echo {17..24}{41..48}` and you'll get the same thing with no for loop. It's "just" a brace expansion.

Comment: Semantics, I guess. "By their fruit ye shall know them." I use the term "loop" simply because that is the apparent behaviour (Queen's English). Whatever we call it, it is iterative in nature. And I would bet that the code that 'does the brace expansion' uses some sort of loop. How else do you iterate through a sequence of numbers from N to M? Let's not lose sight of the bigger picture - the point of this post.

Comment: What if i want to input the ending value for the loop using variable: {1..$var} wher $var = 5 . and i want loop to process 1-5. Please how to do it?